# Optimization of Several Gaussian Distributions with non-linear constraints

Tags: systems-of-equations, normal-distribution, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, kalman-filter

I have the following system of equations
\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 {p_x}\\{p_y}\\{p_z}
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13}\\
 m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23}\\
 m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33}
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 a_x\\a_y\\a_z
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align}
    which in Einstein notation, it simplifies to
    \begin{align*}
 p_i = m_{ij}a_j\quad i,j = 1,2,3
 \end{align*}
    It is assumed that $a_i$, which is the input vector, and $m_{ij}$, which is the transfer function, have Gaussian distributions
    \begin{align*}
 a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\overline{a_i}, \sigma_i^2)\\
 m_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\overline{m_{ij}}, \sigma_{ij}^2)
 \end{align*}

For a transfer function $m_{ij}$, I have three independent measurements
    \begin{align*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 {p_x}_1\\{p_y}_1\\{p_z}_1\\{p_x}_2\\{p_y}_2\\{p_z}_2\\{p_x}_3\\{p_y}_3\\{p_z}_3
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13}&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23}&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33}&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13}\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23}\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33}\\
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 {a_x}_1\\{a_y}_1\\{a_z}_1\\{a_x}_2\\{a_y}_2\\{a_z}_2\\{a_x}_3\\{a_y}_3\\{a_z}_3
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}
    or in matrix form
    \begin{align*}
 P = MA
 \end{align*}

Given $\overline{a_i}$, $\sigma_i^2$, $\overline{m_{ij}}$, and $\sigma_{ij}^2$,  how can I find the vector $P$, having 9 components, with the following three constraints ($P_{12}$ and $P_{23}$ are given as well)
    \begin{align}
 \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
 {p_x}_1 & {p_y}_1 & {p_z}_1\\
 {p_x}_2 & {p_y}_2 & {p_z}_2\\
 {p_x}_3 & {p_y}_3 & {p_z}_3
 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 0
 \end{align}

\begin{align}
 \left({p_x}_1-{p_x}_2\right)^2 + \left({p_y}_1-{p_y}_2\right)^2 + \left({p_z}_1-{p_z}_2\right)^2 = P_{12}^2\\
 \left({p_x}_2-{p_x}_3\right)^2 + \left({p_y}_2-{p_y}_3\right)^2 + \left({p_z}_2-{p_z}_3\right)^2 = P_{23}^2 
 \end{align}

I would appreciate any hint for solving this optimization problem. I hope my problem explanation makes sense and I look forward to any suggestions.